# How to create Parcelable class using following JSON Data?

Tags: android, json, parcelable, parcel

Array key will be change every time when you call api so how to make parcel class.

```
 {
        "status": 200,
        "message": "Ground Schedules",
        "data": {
            "Schedules": {
                "2017-05-04": [
                    {
                        "id": "1216",
                        "ground_id": "100",
                        "ground_court_id": "71",
                        "start_time": "02:00:00",
                        "end_time": "04:00:00",
                        "price": "100.00",
                        "is_available": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "1258",
                        "ground_id": "100",
                        "ground_court_id": "71",
                        "start_time": "02:00:00",
                        "end_time": "04:00:00",
                        "price": "100.00",
                        "is_available": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "1259",
                        "ground_id": "100",
                        "ground_court_id": "71",
                        "start_time": "04:00:00",
                        "end_time": "06:00:00",
                        "price": "100.00",
                        "is_available": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "1215",
                        "ground_id": "100",
                        "ground_court_id": "71",
                        "start_time": "24:00:00",
                        "end_time": "02:00:00",
                        "price": "100.00",
                        "is_available": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "2017-05-05": [
                    {
                        "id": "1266",
                        "ground_id": "100",
                        "ground_court_id": "71",
                        "start_time": "03:00:00",
                        "end_time": "04:00:00",
                        "price": "100.00",
                        "is_available": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "2017-05-06": [
                    {
                        "id": "1268",
                        "ground_id": "100",
                        "ground_court_id": "71",
                        "start_time": "01:00:00",
                        "end_time": "02:00:00",
                        "price": "100.00",
                        "is_available": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "1267",
                        "ground_id": "100",
                        "ground_court_id": "71",
                        "start_time": "24:00:00",
                        "end_time": "01:00:00",
                        "price": "100.00",
                        "is_available": "1"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "GroundBookedSlots": [
                {
                    "id": "1120",
                    "ground_id": "100",
                    "ground_court_id": "71",
                    "start_time": "17:00:00",
                    "end_time": "18:00:00",
                    "price": "500.00",
                    "date": "2017-04-19"
                },
                {
                    "id": "1112",
                    "ground_id": "100",
                    "ground_court_id": "71",
                    "start_time": "17:00:00",
                    "end_time": "18:00:00",
                    "price": "500.00",
                    "date": "2017-04-18"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Json Array is Dynamic . Use **[Iterator](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Iterator.html)**

**To use an iterator, follow these steps −**

1. Obtain an iterator to the start of the collection by calling the
   collection's iterator( ) method.
2. Set up a loop that makes a call to hasNext( ). Have the loop iterate
   as long as hasNext( ) returns true.
3. Within the loop, obtain each element by calling next( ).

**At first, Get Key Value**

```
final JSONObject getJson = JsonObject.getJSONObject("Schedules");
                Iterator  iteratorObj = getJson.keys();
                ArrayList<String> al_getAllArray=new ArrayList<String>();
                while (iteratorObj.hasNext())
                {
                    String getJsonArray = (String)iteratorObj.next();
                    System.out.println("Key: " + Key + "------>" + getJsonArray );
                    al_getAllArray.add(getJsonArray);
                    .....//do your work//.......

                }
```

Comment: Thanks but i want to create Parcelable class like this
public class Schedules implements Parcelable {
}

Comment: @ckpatel I know about `Parcelable ` . May i know why this required for that case ??

Comment: i have working in existing application and in this used parcelable class so and i have no idea about this

Comment: can you help me please

Comment: @ckpatel At first tell me , Need Json dynamic array element at first ??

Comment: @ckpatel where you able to create parcelable class for this ?